# adding items from an array multiple times to the stage

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a for loop which passes 11 times:

```
private var currentItem:uint;
for(var i:uint = 0;i<10;i+){
    addChild(arr[currentItem]);
    currentItem++;
    if(currentItem == arr.length){
    currentItem = 0;
    }
}
```

So the problem is that the array only contains 6 items. So when it comes to the 6th item the `currentItem` resets and the next 4 items that are getting added are the 4 first from the array again. Now when I trace the items, the last 4 trace "null". My question is, how can I add items from the array multiple times without losing its properties etc?

Comment: I have no problem with your code : `public function Test3()
  {
   var arr : Array = new Array(
    new Sprite,
    new Sprite,
    new Sprite,
    new Sprite,
    new Sprite,
    new Sprite
   );
   for(var i:uint = 0;i<10;i++){
    addChild(arr[currentItem]);
    trace(arr[currentItem]);
    currentItem++;
    if(currentItem == arr.length){
     currentItem = 0;
    }
   }
  }
  
  private var currentItem:uint;`
Your problem come maybe from  the fact you don't initialyze currentItem, so your code work only for the first call

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing inherently wrong with your loop. However, a DisplayObject can only be on the display list once. It can't have multiple parents or be a child of the same parent many times. That's why your code isn't working.

Update:

If you want to create new instances from a list of Classes you can do that, but your current approach wont work. This is what you need to do:

```
// the square bracket notation is shorthand for creating an array.
// fill the array with references to *classes* not instances
var classes:Array = [ MyClassOne, MyClassTwo, MyClassThree ];

// we run the loop much as you did, but we can make it much more compact
// by using the modulus operator
// since the array is full of classes, we can use the new operator to 
// create new instances of those classes and add them to the display-list
for(var i:uint = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
    addChild(new classes[i % classes.length]);
}
```

Comment: it shouldnt be the same child though, i just want to create new instances from that child so each instance is different but with the same properties.